# Error while creating App shell in Angular 8

Tags: angular

When I tried to create app shell using CLI command `ng generate app-shell`, it showed:

```
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {}
Errors:
  Data path "" should have required property 'clientProject'.
```

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example or, at least, post your angular.json?

Comment: I was just trying to use App Shell in a complete new project. I followed steps as described in the official doc(https://angular.io/guide/app-shell) but nothing was modified in angular.json and this error was thrown while running this command => ng generate app-shell